# Symfony2: What does $providerKey in UsernamePasswordToken actually do?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I'm trying to understand the authentication layer of Symfony2 (using Symfony 2.8). `UsernamePasswordToken` object is being initialized with:

```
public function __construct($user, $credentials, $providerKey, array $roles = array())
```

Based on some tutorial, I created a method in registration controller for authenticating a user automatically after submitting the registration form.

```
private function authenticateUser(User $user)
{
    $providerKey = 'default'; // your firewall name
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
    $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
}
```

And it works, the thing is... I don't know why it works (and this is the worst feeling). I don't know why this works because it was being said that `$providerKey` should match a firewall, but I can put whatever I want in it, and it will still work. Why is that?

Code scanning suggests me that it is being used only in implementations of `AuthenticationProviderInterface`, but it's hard to go deeper from there.

So... What is `$providerKey` really for, and why doesn't it matter what I put in it when I'm creating `UsernamePasswordToken` object for user authentication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The provider key allows security listeners and providers to distinguish between different tokens when a system might support more than one kind of token. It's largely to prevent these services from getting in each other's way.

Comment: Could you please give just one example when having different tokens from different providers would be useful?

Comment: In our application we have two firewalls, and each one has a different provider key. For instance, the provider key is in the used in the PHP session name to distinguish between the two session tokens a user may have.

Comment: So would it be a good example of ecommerce website, where user could login as employee but also as client (different firewalls), and by providerKey you would know where he logged in?

Comment: Yes, that would be an example. It's mainly if you want different login/logout URLs that you would need it. Although there are probably other ways of tracking where the user logged in.